# What is VA and P.O. BOX?

Tags: word-usage

[image]

In the file I attached above, What is P.O. Box and VA? Could you explain them briefly?

Comment: They are parts of the postal address. Have you tried a Google search for "U.S. postal addresses"? How about [**Wikipedia?**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_(geography)#United_States)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be easily answered with a Google search.

Comment: @user3169: That's a good downvote reason, but a bad close reason; only questions that come down to nothing more than "give me a dictionary entry for word X" are closeable as such. http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65/ask-even-if-the-answer-exists-online

Comment: @NathanTuggy OK, then [*P.O.*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/po#po__19) and [*VA*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/va#va__5). The choice is obvious in context.

Comment: @user3169: A little more reasonable, but e.g. [Onelook](http://onelook.com/?w=p.o.&ls=a) shows a pretty spotty set of results; many dictionaries give entirely the wrong idea or require hunting through long lists of possibilities to get anywhere. That's somewhat less than amazing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about US postal addresses, not English.

Answer (score 3):

P.O. Box would be a location at a post office that someone rents that can hold mail as a physical mailing address. "P.O." would be "Post Office" for the literal meaning. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-office_box) would have more details. Similarly, VA is the 2 letter abbreviation for "Virginia" which is the state that the city is located. [Here](http://www.50states.com/abbreviations.htm) is a list of those abbreviations as each state has one.